# system of differential equations with ode45 in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode45

I have got this model for glucose and insulin, and system of differential equations:

[image: system of differential equations]

Where:

`G(t)` - the plasma glucose concentration at time t
`I(t)` - the plasma insulin concentration at time t
`X(t)`- the interstitial insulin at time t
`Gb` - the basal plasma glucose concentration
`Ib` - the basal plasma insulin concentration

which describe the model. I must do an algorithm to estimate parameters with use ode45 in matlab.

Test data is as follows:

[image: Test data screenshot]

I am not sure how write function for ode45, my idea is as follows:

```
function [] = cwiczenie3_1a(dane)
a=size(dane);
u=[];
y=[];
for i=1:a(1,1)
  g(i,1)=dane(i,2);
  j(i,1)=dane(i,3);
end
[x t]=ode45(@funkcjajeden,[0 100],[0,0]) 
end

function [dg] = funkcjajeden(t,g)
gb=350;
d=0.1;
ib=120;
k1=1;
k2=2;
k3=1;
dg=zeros(size(g));
dg(1)=(k1*(gb-g(1)))-d*g(1);
dg(2)=(k2*(g(2)-ib))-k3*d;
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking a look to [the documentation for ode45](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) to solve the system of differential equations you should write the function in a file, `odefcn.m` in this case:

```matlab
function dg = odefcn(g,k1,k2,k3,gb,ib,d)

  dg = zeros(size(g));
  dg(1) = k1*(gb-g(1)) - d*g(1);
  dg(2) = k2*(g(2)-ib) - k3*d;
```

And then in another file you solve it by doing:

```matlab
gb = 350;
d = 0.1;
ib = 120;
k1 = 1;
k2 = 2;
k3 = 1;

tspan = [0 100];
g0 = [0 0];
[t,g] = ode45(@(t,g) odefcn(g,k1,k2,k3,gb,ib,d), tspan, g0);

plot(t,g(:,1),t,g(:,2))
```

This way you obtain the values for both  `G(t)` an `I(t)` for that initial values and parameters:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIO3s.jpg)

Then, you can compare to the test data and find the value of the parameters.